# Updated angular.js file not being picked up by flask

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, flask

This is sort of bizarre behavior.  I have a flask app, and when I run it, if I inspect the element none of my changes are showing up in the file.

So for example I changed:

```
this.isSet = function(checkTab) {
  if (this.tab === checkTab) {
    return "active";
  };
};
```

to this:

```
this.isSet = function(checkTab) {
  return checkTab === this.tab;
};
```

but when I inspect element on my website, the old version is still showing up when I run the flask app.  I can't imagine why this would be happening.

Comment: Are you editing the right file? Are you saving it? I doubt it's anything with Flask. Are you running with debug on?

Comment: if you run behind a wsgi like gunicorn you have to restart the wsgi process to get certain changes.